# Success message when fails

Tags: c#, sql, exception, try-catch

Hi When i try to run this code when it errors i recive the error "Import Failure - Social" Then i get the message "Inserted"

```
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Social (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Linkedin) VALUES,
        (@Facebook, @Twitter, @Google, @Linkedin)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facebook", FacebookBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Twitter", TwitterBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Google", GoogleBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Linkedin", LinkedInBox.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception sqlcmdsocial)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sqlcmdsocial.Message, "Import Failure - Social");
}
MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
```

Comment: There is an error in your insert query and your "inserted" message should be within the try clause after the executeNonQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your "inserted" messagebox inside the try clause or else it will be executed every time.

There is also a syntax error in you insert query.  There is a "," right after the"values" keyword.

Fix those two issues and it should work correctly.

```
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Social (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Linkedin) VALUES
    (@Facebook, @Twitter, @Google, @Linkedin)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facebook", FacebookBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Twitter", TwitterBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Google", GoogleBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Linkedin", LinkedInBox.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
}
catch (Exception sqlcmdsocial)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sqlcmdsocial.Message, "Import Failure - Social");
}
```

Comment: You can also add this line  to the `ExecuteNonQuery` line: `int rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` Then do `if(rowsAffected > 0 ){ MessageBox.Show("Inserted"); } else { // Do something else }`

Comment: @developer_117 : i would say it's highly unlikely that such a simple statement will return anything else than 1.  If it doesn't insert a row, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the exception, but continuing application execution. Try placing your "Inserted" message inside the Try block (after the ExecuteNonQuery call).